# I am trying to send user an email using Django but redirected to a blank page

Tags: python, django, email

For the above stated problem I am using a form so that as soon as there is a click email is sent to user

**models.py**

```
from django import forms
class Notification(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    message = forms.CharField()
```

**This is views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .models import Notification

    def notification(request):
            form = Notification(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():


                message = form.cleaned_data["message"]
                email = form.cleaned_data["email"]


                subject = 'Order Status at Table'
                from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                to_email = [email,]
                contact_message = "%s"%( 
                        message)

                send_mail(subject, 
                        contact_message, 
                        from_email, 
                        to_email, 
                        fail_silently=True)

            context = {
                "email": email,
                "message": message
            }
            return render(request, "send.html", context)
```

**send.html**

```
<form name="notification" method='POST' action= "">{% csrf_token %}
<select name="message">
    <option value="5 min">5 min</option>
    <option value="10 min">10 min</option>
    <option value="15 min">15 min</option>
    <option value="20 min">20 min</option>
  </select>
  <select name="email">
    <option value="example@example.com">example@example.com</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

As soon as I click the submit button I am redirected to a blank screen(and email is not sent)

In the console I can see the message and the user email passing but email is not sent

In my settings I have configured the mail and its working

Comment: Your form action is not set to do anything. Try changing that so it goes to the appropriate view?

Comment: Did you work out your issue?

Comment: yes I tried but I was exhausted at the end but I will paste my whole views code here

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of things going on in your `notification` view.

1. You are importing the model `Notification` instead of the form one. That's one reason you should name your forms like this `NotificationForm`.
2. You are creating a `context` but if the request is a `GET` one, then this context will have undefined variables.
3. You are hardcoding the form, which is not the Django way. You should create the choices inside the form.

So, change to these please:

```
# forms.py

from django import forms

class NotificationForm(forms.Form):
    EMAIL_CHOICES = (
        ('example@example.com', 'example@example.com'),
    )

    MESSAGE_CHOICES = (
        ('5 min', '5 min'),
        ('10 min', '10 min'),
        ('15 min', '15 min'),
        ('20 min', '20 min'),
    )
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.Select(choices=EMAIL_CHOICES))
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=MESSAGE_CHOICES))
```

Then in your `views.py` file:

```
# views.py

from .forms import NotificationForm 

def notification(request):
    email = ''
    message = ''
    form = NotificationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NotificationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            subject = 'Order Status at Table'
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_email = [email,]
            contact_message = '{}'.format(message)
            send_mail(subject, contact_message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently=True)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'email': email,
        'message': message
    }
    return render(request, "send.html", context)
```

Finally in your `send.html` write these:

```
<form name="notification" method='post' action="">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I actually tried your solution but the problem still persist . I am getting this                         error [25/Mar/2017 12:41:57] "POST /cheforders/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=NM0BFrDinA3c8Qetn6eKBmY9JdDpZwlQ&message=Your+order+will+take+20+min&email=apul.gupta1421%40gmail.com HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Comment: error persisted, but I tried changing request to GET from POST . This time console gave me no error and returned back to same place but email was not sent.

Comment: should I consider adding action in the form

Comment: same error  I am really not getting what the problem is

Comment: I think views is having some problem because in the front end I am only seeing a submit button but not the options but it should come because form was imported in html

Comment: Delete some comments from here and update your question with your current `forms`, `views` and `html` please